# How to perform drag drop in selenium grid

Tags: java, selenium

I  was installed selenium grid successfully but not able to perform drag drop operation in selenium grid. if i run the code in testng it is working as expected, bu for grid it fail i learning selenium grid so unable to fix this issue,

jar: selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar

Selenium JAR: All jar from "selenium-2.45.0" (latest)

***CODE:***

```
public class DragdropElements {WebDriver driver;
String nodeURL;
@BeforeTest
public void draganddrop() throws MalformedURLException
{
    // driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger");
    nodeURL = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
/// cap.setVersion("31.0");
    //cap.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL),cap);
    driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2014/09/drag-and-drop.html");
}

@Test
public void DragdropElements1() throws InterruptedException   
{
WebElement DragFrom = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dragdiv']"));
WebElement DragTo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dropdiv']"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action dragAndDrop3 =  builder.dragAndDrop(DragFrom, DragTo).build();
    dragAndDrop3.perform();

    String Texttocompare = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Blog1']/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/h3")).getText();
    System.out.println(""+Texttocompare);
Assert.assertEquals(Texttocompare, "Drag and Drop");
}
}
```

***Exception:***

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasInputDevices
>     at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.(Actions.java:41)
>     at qa.DragdropElements.DragdropElements1(DragdropElements.java:45)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: Is it HTML5 then there is already a open issue for drag and drop not working. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6315

Comment: @MrunalGosar thanks, please update me ones the fix was done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it might work

```
Actions actionsBuilder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
   .click(elementName)
   .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
Action action = actionsBuilder.build();
action.perform();
```

Not sure why drag and drop isn't working for you. If you're running multi threads in your nodes try running with just tone thread. Also it's worth mentioning your node OS information.

Comment: It's a cast issue on the part of `driver`.  He created it as a `RemoteWebDriver`, rather than a `FirefoxDriver`.

Comment: Hi user1629109, thanks for looking in to it  <br/> unfortunately the provided code is not working. <br/>  if you need some more information from my side please let me know.

Comment: @Girish : In your original code try adding
FirefoxProfile profile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("default");
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);      
and then pass on the profile to capabilities

Comment: @user1629109 i tried with FirefoxProfile and getting the same result as before. it is not working.

Comment: Hey Guys any update on this, if any one having java script that also work for me.